# How can I remove all images and add a new list of images?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Using the Isotope plugin how can I remove all images that currently exist and load in a set of images on a press of a button?

In the documentation it says do this to remove a single item:

```
.isotope( 'remove', $items, callback )
```

How can I remove all the items and then load a new set of items? An example in jsfiddle would be wonderful.

Answer (score 4):

I, too, recently needed to replace all isotope items with a new set of images.

This worked for me:

```
var $isoContainer = $('#image-feed');
$isoContainer.isotope('remove', $isoContainer.isotope('getItemElements'));
$isoContainer.isotope('appended', $newEntries);
$isoContainer.isotope('layout');
```

Comment: instead of using `appended` and `layout` one can just do [`insert`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#insert)  
Available since isotope v1

Answer (score 0):

You could just use jQuery to delete the elements, and then trigger an isotope reLayout.

Example

```
$items.remove(); // you can remove multiple items with jQuery and also append new itmes
$item_parent.isotope('reLayout');
```

Read

It isn't necessary to use isotope to handle node deletions.

[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[.isotope('reLayout')](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#relayout)

Comment: I've tried, $(allCards).remove(); which removes all the images. Then I get new data with $("#content").html( data ); And then I did $('#content').isotope( 'reLayout' ); Isotope doesn't work after this and I have no errors.