# Removing appended isotope items

Tags: ajax, jquery-isotope

I'm appending isotope items via Ajax in Wordpress:

My JS Code:

```
var $news_container = $('#news'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
$news_container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
    itemSelector: '.newsItem',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: '.news-item-sizer',
      gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
    }
});
var has_run = false;
var init_offset = 0;

$('button.showall').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var button = $(this);

    // Disable button
    $(button).removeClass('showall');
    $(button).addClass('showless');

    // Record Nonce
    var nonce = $(this).data("nonce");

    if(has_run == false) {
        button.data('offset', $(this).data("offset"));
        init_offset = $(this).data("offset");
    }

    // Set AJAX parameters
    data = {
        action: 'mft_load_more_ajax',
        init_offset: init_offset,
        offset: button.data('offset'),
        nonce: nonce
    };

    $.post(mft_load_more_ajax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        // Set Container Name
        var response = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(response);

        // Run through JSON
        $.each( response, function( key, value ) {
          // Set Value
          var val = $(value);

          // Set Container
          var $container = $('#news').isotope();

          // Append Val
          $container.append(val).isotope( 'appended', val );

          $(button).html('show less');

        });

        // Set Offset
        var offset = button.data("offset");
        button.data("offset", offset + 11 );

        // If Has Run
        has_run = true;

        return false;
}
```

Until now, this works quite fine. Now I would like to switch the buttontext and it's class to .showless and on the next click all previously appended items should be removed. They all have the class .newsItem.appendedItem.

I tried this method:

```
$('button.showless').click(function(e) {
    var button = $(this);
    console.log('showless');
    $out = $('.newsItem.appendedItem');
    var isotopeInstance = $('#news').data('isotope');
    isotopeInstance.$allAtoms = isotopeInstance.$allAtoms.not($out);
    $out.remove();

    // Disable button
    $(button).removeClass('showless');
    $(button).addClass('showall');

    has_run = false;

    return false;
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, because the showless function is not even being entered, as I don't get a log in the console. What am I overlooking?

Thanks for your help!
Cara

**Update 1:**

I'm getting this error in Google Console.
[image]

Comment: Is your issue unique? Suggest you to check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485281/how-can-i-remove-all-images-and-add-a-new-list-of-images

Comment: Thanks, @mumair, I don't think that I need any help in removing the items. That's something I probably can work out somehow. I just don't understand, why I'm even not able to enter the function. I must overlook something.

Comment: Can you provide `jsfiddle` or `plunker` to debug problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, as I'm working with a full wordpress install. :-/

Comment: Can you show output of this `console.log(response);` before `JSON.parse(response);` Error says response is not valid JSON string.

Comment: also check input `data` type you passing to $.post. `typeof(data)`

Comment: The response I'm getting before (on the first click) is right. It's an array with three divs, that are going to be appended in the isotope grid. How can I check input `data`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133079/discussion-between-mumair-and-caramar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, what was the problem now. But I cleaned the code a little bit with using an if statement, to check if the elements already got appended.

So my final code now looks like this:

```
var $news_container = $('#news'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
$news_container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
    itemSelector: '.newsItem',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: '.news-item-sizer',
      gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
    }
});
var is_appended = false;

$('button.showall').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var button = $(this);

    // Record Nonce
    var nonce = $(this).data("nonce");

    if(is_appended == false) {
        button.data('offset', $(this).data("offset"));

        // Disable button
        button.prop( "disabled" , true );

        // Set AJAX parameters
        data = {
            action: 'mft_load_more_ajax',
            offset: button.data('offset'),
            nonce: nonce
        };

        $.post(mft_load_more_ajax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            // Set Container Name
            var response = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(response);

            // Run through JSON
            $.each( response, function( key, value ) {
              // Set Value
              var val = $(value);

              // Set Container
              var $container = $('#news').isotope();

              // Append Val
              $container.append(val).isotope( 'appended', val );

            });

            // Undo Button Disable
            button.prop( "disabled" , false );
            button.html('Weniger News anzeigen');

            // Set Offset
            // var offset = button.data("offset");
            // button.data("offset", offset + 11 );

            // If Was appended
            is_appended = true;

            return false;

        });

    } else if(is_appended == true) {

        $out = $('.newsItem.appendedItem');            
        $news_container.isotope( 'remove', $out )
        // layout remaining item elements
        .isotope('layout');
        button.html('Alle News anzeigen');

        is_appended = false;
        return false;
    }

});
```

In Chrome everything works perfectly. But just figured out, that in Firefox my Ajax array is completely empty and I'm not able to fetch any data. Probably another problem, I'm going to post separately.